# How can also show null (or zero) values corresponding to Q1 and Q5 values of column on SQLserver?

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

I made this exercise on SQL server: write a query that lists for each cluster the quantity of products that fall within it. The company wants to obtain an analysis of sales with respect to the average quantity of each product present in each order, classifying them into six clusters: Q1 (<15), Q2 (15-20), Q3 (21-25), Q4 (26-30), Q5 (31-35), Q6(>35). Write a query that lists, for each product, the product name and the cluster to which it belong. The database is northwind

```
select count(ProductName) as prod_num ,cluster

from  (
        select  ProductName,
        case 
        when avg(Quantity) < 15 then 'Q1'
        when avg(Quantity) <= 20 then 'Q2'
        when avg(Quantity) between 21 and 25 then 'Q3'
        when avg(Quantity) between 26 and 30 then 'Q4'
        when avg(Quantity) between 31 and 35 then 'Q5'
        else 'Q6'
        end
        as cluster
        from [Order Details] od  join Products pr on od.ProductID=pr.ProductID
        group by  ProductName
        ) as clusters  
group by  cluster
order by cluster
```

```
OUTPUT
22  Q2
35  Q3
18  Q4
2   Q6
```

I also need to display values for Q1 and Q5.

Comment: I guess, the second case in your query should be when avg(Quantity) between 15 and  20 then 'Q2'

Comment: sorry, but nothing change

Comment: Sidebar: Why are you grouping by ProductName? Do you have multiple ProductIDs with the same name? (The reason I ask is it seems the join to products _might_ be unnecessary.)

Comment: ...and because grouping by a longer (and variable-width) name is going to be far more expensive than grouping by a fixed-width, 4-byte integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always seed your initial counts, for example:

```
declare @clusters table (prod_num int, cluster nchar(2));
insert into @clusters values
    (0, 'Q1'),(0, 'Q2'),(0, 'Q3'),(0, 'Q4'),(0, 'Q5'),(0, 'Q6');
    
select 
    t1.cluster,
    t1.prod_num + isnull(t2.prod_num, 0) as prod_num
from 
    @clusters t1
    left join
        (
            select count(ProductName) as prod_num ,cluster
            from  (
                    select  ProductName,
                    case 
                    when avg(Quantity) < 15 then 'Q1'
                    when avg(Quantity) between 15 and 20 then 'Q2'
                    when avg(Quantity) between 21 and 25 then 'Q3'
                    when avg(Quantity) between 26 and 30 then 'Q4'
                    when avg(Quantity) between 31 and 35 then 'Q5'
                    else 'Q6'
                    end
                    as cluster
                    from [Order Details] od  join Products pr on od.ProductID=pr.ProductID
                    group by  ProductName
                    ) as clusters  
            group by  cluster
        ) t2
    on t1.cluster = t2.cluster
order by t1.cluster;
```

Now we have an initial count of zero for all groups and add to that the counts we found in our query.

Untested so please let me know if you find errors...

Comment: Great!!! It works, is there any other way to get the same result with create table statement instead of declare table?

Comment: Yes, you can always use a temp table or even a normal table... For example, change `declare @clusters table` to `create table #clusters` and refer to `#clusters` instead of `@clusters`

Answer (score 1):

You can make your query much simpler by storing the clusters *and the ranges* in a table (so that you can reuse it across other similar queries that use the same breakdown). I use a #temp table here but there's no reason this couldn't be a static, permanent dimension table.

```
CREATE TABLE #clusters(cluster char(2), lo int, hi int,
  INDEX cix_cl CLUSTERED(lo,hi));

INSERT #clusters VALUES('Q1', 0,14),('Q2',15,20),('Q3',21,25),
                       ('Q4',26,30),('Q5',31,35),('Q6',36,2000000000);

SELECT prod_num = COUNT(p.ProductName), cl.cluster
FROM #clusters AS cl
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT pr.ProductName, avgQ = AVG(od.Quantity) 
    FROM dbo.[Order Details] AS od
    INNER JOIN dbo.Products AS pr
    ON od.ProductID = pr.ProductID
    GROUP BY pr.ProductName
) AS p
ON p.avgQ BETWEEN cl.lo AND cl.hi
  GROUP BY cl.cluster;
```

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JczRk4mj).

And again, unless `ProductName` is not unique and you really care about averages across different IDs with the same name as opposed to just product IDs, the join is unnecessary and you could simplify even further:

```
SELECT prod_num = COUNT(p.ProductID), cl.cluster
FROM #clusters AS cl
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT ProductID, avgQ = AVG(Quantity) 
    FROM dbo.[Order Details]
    GROUP BY ProductID
) AS p
ON p.avgQ BETWEEN cl.lo AND cl.hi
  GROUP BY cl.cluster;
```

Comment: Pretty good, thank you very much! But I can't change the query because it's based on another one in an exercise.

Comment: Very good. If you are going for efficiency then you may as well make a clustered index on `#clusters`

Comment: @Charlieface Maybe, I'm usually a proponent of clustered indexes but with 6 rows on the small side of a nested loop I'm not sure it will amount to anything.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a temp table or table variable, you can use a virtual `VALUES` clause to generate all the rows.

You can also significantly simplify this by putting the range numbers into that table also.

```sql
select 
    t1.cluster,
    count(t2.AvgQuantity) as prod_num
from (VALUES
  ('Q1', -999999, 15),
  ('Q2', 15, 20),
  ('Q3', 20, 25),
  ('Q4', 25, 30),
  ('Q5', 30, 35),
  ('Q6', 35, 999999)
) t1(cluster, low, hi)
left join (
    select
      ProductName,
      avg(Quantity) as AvgQuantity
    from Products pr
    join [Order Details] od on od.ProductID = pr.ProductID
    group by
      pr.Id,
      pr.ProductName
) t2 on t2.AvgQuantity > t1.low AND t2.AvgQuantity <= t1.hi
group by
  t1.cluster
order by
  t1.cluster;
```

For efficiency (as well as possibly accuracy), you should also group by the product ID or primary key.

Note that the above query only gets you results for products that were actually sold. To include *all* products, change the innermost `join` to a `left join`

Comment: FWIW I suggested a permanent table for reuse, not for performance, but also I would have put the range values into the `VALUES` clause to eliminate the clunky `CASE` expressions.